# Combining variable and output number in R

Tags: r

if i have data list such as

```
a = c(1,2,3,4)
```

and

```
b3 = 400
```

how to make a new variable by combining the letter "b" and output a[3] so when I run it, it appears as b3 = 400

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You want a new variable called `b3` that outputs `400` when you run `b3`?

Comment: i mean, i want to concate letter "b" and output a[3] as the results will be "b3", and when I run it, "b3" will same as b3 that is 400

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `assign` ?

```
assign(paste0("b", a[3]), 400)
```

If you already have a variable named `b3` with the value `400`, then perhaps you want the inverse operation, `get`:

```
get(paste0("b", a[3]))
[1] 400
```

Comment: is there any simple method? 
i think what my teacher wanted is like calling a subset, for ex : b$a[3] ?

Comment: I edited the answer, perhaps this is what you want to do?

Comment: thankyou verymuch for your answer